# Is there any way to remark the Be Nice point from the Help Center?

Tags: discussion

I’m nearly over a month here, on GD.SE. Very happy to find a place to share knowledge about one of the things I love the most, my profession. I must admit that at the beginning it was difficult, some errors of miss-understandings, unknowledge about how the site works, language, etc. But what surprised me most, and I confess it was not easy to me to understand, was the level of *aggressiveness* that exists on the site. Yes, *aggressiveness*, *haters*, *arrogance*, whatever.

I extract some paragraphs from the **Help Center**, specifically from > **Our model** > **Be nice**:

> **Do not be a jerk.**
>
> These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
> • **Name-calling**. Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that are personal even when they are applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
>
> • **Bigotry of any kind**. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just do not.)
>
> • **Inappropriate language or attention**. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is dating site.
>
> • **Harassment and bullying**. If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, disengage - we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page.

I think in this month I have seen **each of these points** reproduced in different answers and comments.

I already say that at first I had a bit of trouble, but my passion for Graphic Design was bigger than the attacks, sometimes to my answers and I think in a couple of times to my person (this second point is not so important, I know very well where I am, it's just information).

**It looks like a joke?**

What kind of interpretation have that after answered a couple of questions my first day in GD.SE I started to get lower scores at **ALL** my interventions in StackOverflow, site in which I have not participated since the beginning of this year? It has an online connection? Has there been any suspicious intervention?  Well, it seems a joke to me to see the level of simplicity that mediocrity can bring, although this is not an attack, is just some personal thinking.

Personally, I don't see the point of commenting a question that I think is wrong if I don't bring the correct answer or at least the direction to take to the correct one. And I think I would never do that in the terms in which those comments are usually given, such as: –At the font that you have put the S is different!–, or after clarifying in the answer that I give is an alternative in another application, the comment that always comes up –That's not what the OP request –. I have the feeling that some people has their answers in a doc file and copy/paste them according to the occasion.
What's the point of commenting that the answer is not the right one without providing an alternative? This is the same level as somebody who requests a tutorial in a question.

Sometimes I see questions, even kind of shy writing, with the immediate closing option without even a little explanation, and when I say immediate means one or two seconds after the question is online. It looks like the OP is the one who write the (close) at the end of the question. And if the OP has to read the reason for the possible closure, there are even times that the reason does not correspond at all to the type of question. In addition to the *haters*, there are the *closers*, who simply propose to close questions.

To me it is a pity that some of these situations happen here. In my case it is not so important, I understood how it works and I adapt myself, just participating if it is interesting and if it is not, I simply let it go. The problem is that these types of attitudes drive people away. A first-year Graphic Design student who timidly ask a question and after a second get eight angry dogs coming over, not only will not never return anymore, but also will convey to all the colleagues from the school or university that participating in GD.SE does not make any sense. And I think this is a shame.

Will it be necessary to be more demanding with the Be Nice point in some way?

For the rest, I am still very happy to share things and knowledge with all the people here. In a month I have learned a lot and I really appreciate all the orthographic corrections (I hope nobody takes this wrong and send me to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange).

Comment: I have some leads to answer but I feel your question is a bit unprecise as it stands (rudeness vs. pointing a problem in an answer without giving an alternative vs. getting lower scores vs. close votes, especially, I think are all different problems). I think it might be helpful to focus on what you want to discuss specifically or break down in multiple questions :-)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: I started asking questions on StackOverflow a few years ago, being a real ignorant about coding. I never had the feeling that SO is a kind of unwelcome or rude site. Stack Overflow is a fairy tail compared to GD.SE.

Comment: @Emilie My question steel being the one from the title. Other comments are just points that I remark as examples of what I'm trying to explain, actually for them I don't need any answer. There has to be a kind of warning about misplaced comments that do nothing but generate the displeasure of the person being questioned. Have you ever used HabboHotel. I do not know how it is now, at the beginning it was a place made in a very smart way. Every time you made a rude comment, a pop bubble appear saying – this is a place to have fun, those kind of comments are not accepted in HabboHotel –.

Comment: Hm, my impression from SO is a polar opposite of yours. I have been pestered off that site by the few interactions I had with it by snooty, arrogant and dismissive users. And yay for your post and your presence here! You have been a *huge* help. I completely share your opinion that 'be nice' should be emphasised further and maybe enforced a bit more strictly. I concur with Emilie that your post could use some focus, though. If you want to discuss things or even just vent and get another perspective, do join us in [The Ink Spot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot)

Comment: Yes Vincent, Welz made the same offer about participating at the chat. I admit that I'm a bit lazy with chats in general. I will try. The difference between answering a question and participating in a chat is that in the answers I put the necessary time to develop them, a chat involves many small seconds of attention and for me it is too much distraction.

Comment: Don't see it as any way of pressuring you there :). Just know we're around and can help you handle the more difficult situations. And besides, we're a pretty laid-back lot back there and the room isn't too busy regularly.

Comment: This also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311737/lets-hold-language-in-comments-to-the-same-standard-as-posts

Comment: @Emilie Reading some of the answers to that post makes me so incredibly sad.

Comment: A question from a OP with 38 score points, means that is the 1st time he post on GD.SE. It's easy to see he is not that good in design. Tell me, what kind of "pedagogy" this answer has: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110927/120647 Imagine this was the only answer obtained by this OP together with -5 points. Do you get sad? This was one of the few times I react to an answer with a comment and the only one time I put a -1 point score to an answer, just because made me very sad. More than if he is right or not, just the way. Actually I think my answer is harder, but positive.

Comment: @Danielillo The wording on the answer could be greatly improved but ultimately I agree with the substance of the post (that logos don't need to be descriptive). If you see someone being outright rude (as per "Be Nice" rules you pasted above) leave a flag). If the tone is rough but not hostile, you could consider editing the post. The answer is short but I saw it as useful, clear and offered examples so I did not see a reason to downvote. It tackled a [different issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) of the OP that other answers had not adressed.

Comment: When the OP is asking for a critic to his logo, answering him: —Make a logo instead– is not a bit destructive? Who has enough level here to say that? The logo he made is that one and he is asking about this logo. I insist, if this had being the only one answer, It is totally destructive for someone with intentions to make something in Graphic Design.

Comment: @Danielillo I mentioned only the part about the logo being descriptive (it is a critique of the logo, and targets the specific "Is it boring?"). I disagreed about telling the user to create a logotype instead, because there is not enough information to make that claim, but it is an option the OP can consider for themselves. I think it's a bit misled to speculate on "What if this had been the only answer" because it likely wouldn't be; there is a lot less incentive to post an answer where there are already multiple answers including a chosen answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79460/discussion-on-question-by-danielillo-is-there-any-way-to-remark-the-be-nice-poin).

Comment: [Answering bad font request questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/111081/30216) instead of properly closing and/or commenting leads to the site being polluted with such lazy requests. There is a close reason *especially tailored to such cases*.

Comment: Nice, I will keep it in mind. The relation with this post is?

Comment: "... unknowledge about how the site works …"

Comment: Oh, I see, flag me every time in the future I will do it again. Sometimes is better to leave a satisfied customer than follow some rules, specially when you have the right information about the customer needs. Find this special font took me 5 sec, and I assure you that it does not appear in any font identifier. Anyway, your comment is just about a sentence of this post, but not about the real problem I'm talking about, it does not even help to find a minimum thread of solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You hit some nails but you bent them on the way in. This boils down to a rant due to the amount of negativity in between the few valid points. If you can think of realistic improvements that take into account the complexities of this system model please put them forward. For now I have to downvote because this does nothing but bring negativity, much like the comments you despise but on a more visible level.

Comment: FWIW i agree the rules are silly bordering stupid. SVJ all the way